# angular-file-upload - display uploaded image in browser without streaming it from backend

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using [nervgh/angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) to let the user take a photo from his mobile phone camera and upload it. It works fine, but now I want to display the image too. Of course I could add that functionality to my backend and just use the img-tag and point it to the URL. But since I upload the my JavaScript file already has to have the file at some point, right?
How do i display it?
I tried it like this:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG,{{uploadedImage}}">
```

but couldn't get it to work. According to the [wiki of angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) I have control over an "FileItem", but I can't seem to figure out where the actual file-date is stored.

So my question is: Is it possible to use img tag with ng-src to display a file that is directly stored in JavaScript as byte array and where does angular-file-upload store the actual array-data

Comment: so you want to preview the image of uploaded in your app or browser??

Comment: Exactly. I want to display the file the user just uploaded without calling the backend if that's possible  (which i think should be)

Comment: is it okay for you to show the preview before uploading?

Comment: Yes, you can directly make use of the image that the user is trying to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of `ngf-thumbnail` option

```
<div|span|...
 *ngf-thumbnail="file" //Generates a thumbnail version of the image file
 ngf-size="{width: 20, height: 20, quality: 0.9}" the image will be resized to this size
        // if not specified will be resized to this element`s client width and height.
 ngf-as-background="boolean" //if true it will set the background image style instead of src attribute.
>
```

Take a look at this fiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/)

```
<img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb">
```

This line is helping us to show a thumbnail of the image being uploaded by the user, you can choose different html tags as suggested above. You have to link the image using the file name, the `ng-model` in that case is picFile and that is being used as `ngf-thumbnail`.

You can use your own css on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could use fileReader.
bind the ngModel file then convertit to base64 and use it as the image source

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(scope.ngModel);
    reader.onload = function(readerResult) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.mysrc = reader.result;
        });

    };
```